# Legal Questions

Tags: discussion

Is there a place where I can ask questions concerning patent law for free?  I know that this is an excellent resource for questions related to patents in general, but I have a legal question regarding a specific application restriction, and I need to speak to someone with knowledge of patent law.

Answer (score 0):

Ask Patents doesn't just have to be for general patent questions--questions about specific applications or patents are *sometimes* allowable, primarily when they are, in fact, legal in nature (compared to technical).

If you're wondering what's covered by a patent or application, or what that coverage means, this should actually be a pretty good site to ask on. [Law Stack Exchange](//law.stackexchange.com) is another option, if it really is off-topic here. Otherwise, I'd generally just recommend finding a patent agent or attorney. Many offer free or cheap initial consultations, so that might be an option.

It would help if you could include a basic outline of what you're looking to ask in your meta question here, if you'd like a more specific answer.